# How to install strings in Ubuntu server

Tags: 16.04, server

I installed Ubuntu server 16.04.3 LTS but I cannot find the `strings` command:

```
$ sudo strings /data/storage
sudo: strings: command not found

$ man strings
No manual entry for strings
```

How am I supposed to install it?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to install binutils:

```
sudo apt-get install binutils
```

That should do the job.

Comment: I had to prepend with `sudo` myself, but it worked.

Comment: Thank you @NitinSavant - I've edited my answer with "sudo"

Answer (score -4):

It may be already installed but under the name `strings-GNU` instead of `strings`.  You'll need to create a link in `/usr/bin`.

```
ln -s strings-GNU strings
```